# show that there exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ $f_n(z)$ has $k$ roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

The situations is as follows. We have sequence of holomorphic functions $\{f(n)\}$ which is defined on a open $U$ in $\overline{B(0,1)}$. Suppose now that this sequence converges uniformly to a function $f$ which is holomorphic on $U$ and that $f$ has $k$ roots (multiplicity included). Now I have to show that there exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ the function $f_n(z)$ has $k$ roots. This is what I tried. The sequence converges uniformly, so for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $z\in\overline{B(0,1)}$ we have that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ provided that $n>N$. This implies we have a holomorphic function $h$ such that $f(z)+h(z)=f_n(z)$ with $|h(z)|<\epsilon$. Now we can choose $\epsilon$ so small that on the boundary of $U$, call it $C$, we have $|f(z)|>|h(z)|$. Now we can use Rouches theorem, which says that the number of roots (with multiplicity) of $f(z)+h(z)$ is the same as that of $f(z)$. So this proves it.

Is this proof correct? I am not 100% sure whether it is correct. If its not, what should I then do?

EDIT: My doubt lies in the fact that I am not sure if $f(z)\neq0$ on $C$ the boundary of $D$. Because then we don't have $|f|>|h|$ on $C$ always. What to do about this?